# Is this the correct way to define a table relationship in Sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

I find the [Sequelize docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations) are long and hard to understand if you are using tables that don't follow their conventions.

If I have two tables:

```
people
(
  people_id - uuid
  name - text
)

parties
(
  parties_id - uuid 
  people_id - uuid  (foreign key)
)
```

**Am I right to define my models like this?**

```
function getPeople()
{
  let entity = {};
  entity['people_id'] = {type: Sequelize.UUID, primaryKey: true, allowNull : false};
  entity['name'] = Sequelize.TEXT;
  return sequelize.define('dbo.people', entity, options);
}

function getParties()
{
  let entity = {};
  entity['parties_id'] = {type: Sequelize.UUID, primaryKey: true, allowNull : false};
  entity['people_id'] = 
  {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    references: {model: getPeople(), key: 'people_id', deferrable: Sequelize.Deferrable.INITIALLY_DEFERRED}
  };      
  const parties = sequelize.define('dbo.parties', entity, options);
  parties.belongsTo(this.getPeople(), {foreignKey: 'people_id'});
  return parties;
}
```

Assumptions:

- If I leave out the 'belongsTo' part then as I understand the docs it won't actually be an association, so I couldn't pull out related data in queries using include:[]
- If I leave out the 'references' part then I have no way of specifying the local field name, 'people_id', to be different from the convention 'peopleId' nor a way of setting 'deferrable'
- I assume I can use getPeople() to return a class for use in foreign keys and it doesn't have to be a singleton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I leave out the 'belongsTo' part then as I understand the docs it won't actually be an association, so I couldn't pull out related data in queries using include:[]

Correct - And with only belongsTo you'll only be able to do `Parties.findAll(include People)` - to do it the other way around you need to set up the reverse association as well.

> If I leave out the 'references' part then I have no way of specifying the local field name, 'people_id', to be different from the convention 'peopleId' nor a way of setting 'deferrable'

Yep

> I assume I can use getPeople() to return a class for use in foreign keys and it doesn't have to be a singleton

You might run into subtle problems if you have several instances of the same model - The general pattern is to define each model in a separate file and require it once. Everywhere you need to access the model you can access it from the sequelize instance - see https://github.com/sequelize/express-example

Comment: Other than the singleton thing, I mean. I don't get in this class where 'models' comes from in the associate method: https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/blob/master/models/user.js. Is it called by Sequelize? By the app code?

Comment: The are injected from index.js, which first requires all models, then calls `associate` to set up the associations https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/blob/master/models/index.js