# How do I make a self-referential foreign key in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

Below is my model definition for the `leases` table.  As you can see, I'm getting an error because I can't reference a key on a model I haven't defined yet.

Line 56 works fine to set the key's relationship because I have already created the model. **But how do I access the model on line 40 before I've created the model?**

[image]

Here's what getForeignKey() does:

```
  getForeignKey(name: string, foreignModel: any): any {
    return {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      references: {
        'model': foreignModel,
        'key': name,
        'deferrable': Sequelize.Deferrable.INITIALLY_DEFERRED,
        'allowNull': true
      }
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, removing my entire answer because you're already associating the model to itself. That's what `result.belongsTo(result, { foreignKey: 'renewed_from__lease_id' })` is doing. Does that not fulfil your needs?

Comment: Unfortunately I need both lines. I asked exactly how to define foreign keys a while back and had my answer checked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37297797/is-this-the-correct-way-to-define-a-table-relationship-in-sequelize

Comment: I see from that question you asked about defining the "local" field to be different from "convention". I think that's settable by adding `as: 'whateverYouWantThePropToBeCalled'`. I've never come across the deferrable property though, so can't comment on that.